# Replacing Material-ui with Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, admin-on-rest

I want to use a material ui component to make it similar to bootstrap component

I need to make a component in my application which uses material ui components to look like components in bootstrap.. the reason for this is so I can have synchronized feel with another application developed with bootstrap..

Can I overwrite the properties of the components somehow?

Comment: Do you have a specific code example?

Comment: Sorry ! I had to edit the question I posted , realized I miss wrote my question !  ..

Comment: So you're searching for a theme/styling solution that will make material-ui look like bootstrap?

Comment: I need to make a component in my application which uses material ui components to look like components in bootstrap.. the reason for this is so I can have synchronized feel with another application developed with bootstrap.. just wanted to know how i can overwrite the properties of the components

Comment: Note: Asking for documentation / tutorials is considered off topic for Stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question to include some code examples

Comment: yes @JulesDupont

Comment: the main problem im facing is .. im using admin on rest which has MUI **loosely coupled** as per their docs ! If theres a way to replace the MUI   module and replace it with something like reactstrap or something similar !

Comment: Using a theme to make material-ui look like bootstrap is theoretically possible but will be quite a bit of work so I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, you'll need to rewrite the UI layer of admin-on-rest as per [this issue](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/issues/249).

Comment: thanks @JulesDupont